# How to update a boolean field in Oracle table

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, sql-update

I am a novice Oracle user. I wanted to update a boolean field in my table for one of the record. Which one of these statements is correct ?

```
update MyTable set myBooleanColumn = 1 where UserId= 'xx12345';

or 


update MyTable set myBooleanColumn = '1' where UserId= 'xx12345';
```

any help is greatly appreciated!! thanks !

Comment: There is no such thing as a boolean data type for oracle tables.  You have to do one of your two options - create a field of varchar2(1) and maybe set to Y/N, or a number field, and set to 1/0

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It depends on how the field is defined.

If its defined as a CHAR(1) field, then you can store 'Y'/'N' or 'T'/'F' in it.   To update the field, you'd use the quotes as it would be a string literal.

```
UPDATE TestTable set myCharBooleanColumn = 'Y';
```

If the field is defined as NUMERIC, then the convention is 0=false and 1 or -1 is true  (I've seen both).

```
UPDATE TestTable set myNumericBooleanColumn = 1;
```

Many people will advocate the CHAR(1) approach, but in the real world - you see both.  It depends on how the boolean is implemented.

You can read more in Oracle's docs on Datatypes
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/datatype.htm

Answer (score 4):

There is no such thing as a Boolean field in Oracle so your field is either a numeric field or a character field. If it's a numeric field you don't need to quote the number; if it's a character field you should quote the string.

You can find out the type of the column by querying [USER_TAB_COLUMNS](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e40402/statviews_5475.htm#sthref3105):

```
select *
  from user_tab_columns
 where table_name = 'MYTABLE'
   and column_name = 'MYBOOLEANCOLUMN'
```

or by [describing](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve019.htm#SQPUG040) the table.

Comment: Update: in Oracle version 23c a boolean type was introduced: https://oracle-base.com/articles/23c/boolean-data-type-23c

Comment: If you've got the time add a new answer @AndrewAllaire!

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing as Boolean field in Oracle.

The best what you can do is to create the table like this:-

```
create table ABC(bool char(1) check (bool in ('N','Y'));
```

Then simple update like

```
UPDATE ABC set bool = 'Y';
```

**WHY TAKING CHAR?**

There is no support for **BOOLEAN, BIT, or TINYINT** data types so **char** would be the best as it takes 1 byte